# Auto-adjust Images in Container

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to code my website so the images displayed in the div container fit perfectly to the window regardless of what resolution your screen is. I would also like the images to shrink when the browser window is resized.

Here is my website: http://www.simonsamuel.com/stella-supplement

Comment: The easiest way is to use relative sizing with percents to get it resize with the window, in more complexe, you can even use @media. But In the case, you want more features, you should use the JS resize event you can catch with jQuery.

Comment: You can never fit an image perfectly to a window regardless of resolution a.) because there are so many resolutions and 2.) because there are so many aspect ratios. That doesn't include whatever oddness a user imparts on a browser. You would have to perform several calculations to determine things like crop. You may want to look at a something like this - http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/ to see what they do and if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In `project_content` you set the width in pixels (1036px) try to use relative sizing just like @Loenix said.

```
.project_content {
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-top:0;
  width:100%; /*after: width:1036px;*/
}
```